# Facebook graph preview not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have added some Open Graph meta tags to a website and checkt it through the debugger tool.

The meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="ZOHO, het Rotterdamse maakkwartier." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://zohorotterdam.nl" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://zohorotterdam.nl/web/bundles/zoho/images/facebook.jpg" />
<meta property="og:description" content="ZOHO is het Rotterdamse maakkwartier: een woon- en werkplek aan de rand van het centrum, voor en door makers in design, kunst, cultuur, film, muziek, media, tech, food, architectuur en urban planning. Kom meemaken, kijken, proeven, jezelf verbazen en inspireren. Explore the new in ZOHO!" />
```

Response from graph api:

```
{
    id: "851464644881132",
    created_time: "2014-06-01T07:45:06+0000",
    description: "ZOHO is het Rotterdamse maakkwartier: een woon- en werkplek aan de rand van het centrum, voor en door makers in design, kunst, cultuur, film, muziek, media, tech, food, architectuur en urban planning. Kom meemaken, kijken, proeven, jezelf verbazen en inspireren. Explore the new in ZOHO!",
    image: [
        {
            height: 1313,
            url: "http://zohorotterdam.nl/web/bundles/zoho/images/facebook.jpg",
            width: 2500
        }
    ],
    is_scraped: true,
    title: "ZOHO, het Rotterdamse maakkwartier.",
    type: "website",
    updated_time: "2014-06-25T16:11:09+0000",
    url: "http://zohorotterdam.nl/"
}
```

So far so good. BUT! When I create a new post on facebook and put in our link (http://zohorotterdam.nl) and hit spacebar to trigger the ajax fetching the link details nothing happens. The loader gif that is supposed to tell you that it is fetching only show up for a nano second and than disappears. Nothing else happens...

I checked the XHR response in chrome debugger tools which shows me Facebook is returning a 500 server error:

```
Request URL:https://www.facebook.com/ajax/composerx/attachment/link/scraper/?scrape_url=http%253A%252F%252Fzohorotterdam.nl&remove_url=%2Fajax%2Fcomposerx%2Fattachment%2Fstatus%2F&attachment_class=_4j&__av=631637125&composerurihash=2
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but noticed it didn't happen in Incognito mode. I tried disabling all my extensions, but that didn't do the trick. Finally, I got it working again by going to `chrome://settings`, showing the *Advanced Settings* and then clicking the *Reset browser button*. Whatever got cleaned up, posting to Facebook works again.